# [Vue Warn]: Property "toggleFavorites" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was creating some web app with vuejs2 CLI options API and I tried to create an event emitter but it keeps saying it has an error in the console and doesn't show up anything when the button which has the event emitter  is clicked.

The error is shown in the console

[image: 1]

And this was my code in the child component:

```
<template>
  <li>
    <h2>{{ name }} {{ friendIsFavorite ? "(Favorite)" : "" }}</h2>
    <button @click="toggleFavs">Toggle Favorite</button>
    <button @click="toggleDetails">Show Details</button>
    <ul v-if="detailsAreVisible">
      <li><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ phoneNumber }}</li>
      <li><strong>Email:</strong> {{ emailAddress }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

The first button with the toggleFavs method is the one I sent an event emitter with this method

```
toggleFavs() {
      this.$emit("toggle-fav", this.id);
    },
```

The code on the main App.vue component is this:

```
<template>
  <header> <h1>My Friends</h1></header>
  <ul>
    <friend-contact
      v-for="friend in friends"
      :key="friend.id"
      :id="friend.id"
      :name="friend.name"
      :phone-number="friend.phone"
      :email-address="friend.email"
      :is-favorite="friend.isFavorite"
      @toggle-fav="toggleFavorites"
    ></friend-contact>
  </ul>
</template>
```

where the method of the event is defined as:

```
toggleFavorites() {
      // const targetedFriend = this.friends.find(
      //   (friend) => friend.id === friendId
      // );
      // console.log(targetedFriend);
      // targetedFriend.isFavorite = !targetedFriend.isFavorite;
      alert("This Works"); //just for demonstration but not working
```

help me out guys I'm stuck.

here is the [code](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

Comment: Please specify the vue version and the syntax used

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The problem is in parts that were omitted

Comment: the bits and pieces of code you've shown don't show if you are doing it right ... perhaps if you're using the composition API you forgot to return `toggleFavourites` from `setup`

Comment: I am using the Vue CLI and the options API

Comment: Please share the code that wraps `toggleFavorites`

Comment: `mehtod` should be `methods`

Comment: still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with your code. The first was mentioned by @BoussadjraBrahim and it was a typo (mehtod instead of methods). The second problem was not importing your **FriendContact** component in the App.vue and adding it to the *components* object.

```
<script>
import FriendContact from './FriendContact.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    FriendContact
},
...
methods: {
...
</script>
```

Fixed example [code](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)